# JAXB - generated classes implement interface

Tags: java, interface, jaxb

Is there a way to configure [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to so that a generated class implements a specified interface?  I'm intending to use JAXB generated classes as DAO's and they should be able implement my DAO interface.

Comment: The same as [Generating a JAXB class that implements an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271980).

Comment: Thanks @dma_k I'll mark it for closure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a JAXB class that implements an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271980/generating-a-jaxb-class-that-implements-an-interface)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [interface injection](https://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/interface-insertion/) plugin for XJC lets you do this.

Comment: the website doesn't exist anymore, is the solution obsolete? What is the way to do it now?

Comment: I'm going nuts trying to make this work. The referred link doesn't work anymore and <xjc:superInterface> applies to ALL the generated objects which most of the times is useless! Anyone know if this interface injection plugin can still be used and how?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it looks like the interface-injection plugin mentioned in some of the other answers is no longer well supported. In fact, I'm having trouble finding the JAR for download.

Thankfully, the [JAXB2 Basics Plugins](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins) provides a similar mechanism for adding an interface to the generated JAXB stubs (see the [Inheritance plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin)).

The JAXB2 Basics Plugins documentation includes instructions for using the plugin with Ant and Maven.

The JAXB2 Basics Plugins provides a number of other utilities which you might also find useful (such as autogeneration of equals, hashCode, and toString methods).

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the JAXB2 Basics Plugin lacks now of any documentation. This is the only site left: http://static.highsource.org/jaxb2-basics/jaxb2-basics-tools/project-info.html

Comment: Here's a maven sample configuration that shows how to use 'jaxb2-basics` as a extension to `cxf-xjc-plugin`: https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/8163296