# JAXB Marshalling - extending an existing class

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, base-class

I am in need of creating a series of Java objects via XML using JAXB that all extend a common base class that is already created (not using JAXB).  For example, let's say I have following JAXB classes that I am trying to generate:

```
Penguin.xml  -> Penguin.java
Robin.xml -> Robin.java
Cardinal.xml -> Cardinal.java
```

I already have an existing base class called `Bird.java` that I wish the three classes above to extend.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is very simple: you need to to create a JAXB binding file with following contents:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
>

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <!-- All beans should extend this base class: -->
        <xjc:superClass name="org.mycompany.common.Bird" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

More information on this option (and other sweet things) you can find [here](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/jaxb20-fcs/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#superclass).

Comment: Is there a way to specify witch classes extend Bird class. What if I want only Robin and Cardinal to extend Bird class?

Comment: +1 also if you get an error: "vendor extension bindings (jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes) are not allowed in the strict mode." your should use -extension, if in maven pom use: <configuration><args><arg>-extension</arg>...in maven-jaxb2-plugin

Comment: @Chobicus: The answer to your question is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4984018/267197) in particular you need to activate [Inheritance plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin).