# How to make JAXB Classes with parent child relationship

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have problem to make JAXB classes for parent-child relationship with [JAXB / XJC parent-child-parent navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342888/jaxb-xjc-parent-child-parent-navigation)

I think implementation to `void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent)`. It should be create super class for all jaxb classes.

So, I binding superclass using xjc reffered [JAXB Marshalling - extending an existing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364178/jaxb-marshalling-extending-an-existing-class)

But while unmarshall xml file. occurred some exception '@XmlValue is not allow on a class that derives another class.'

Some solutions `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` And `@XmlTransient` not works for me.

What should i do?

May i use MOXy?
If this situation works good for use MOXy. Have any guide document to use it in SpringBoot?

This is my super class

```java
public class SuperClass {
    private Object parent;
    
    public void setParent(Object parent) {this.parent = parent}
    
    public Object getParent() {return this.parent}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use this [XJC Parent Pointer Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Parent-Pointer-Plugin) which will be available in jaxb-tools 4.0.1.

Adding this plugin will need a runtime dependency.

If not targeting jakarta based JAXB classes, you can use the following maven coordinates `org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons:parent-pointer-plugin:1.0` from where the plugin came from. It will be backported in jaxb-tools v2 too but I can't tell the release date of 4.0.1 or 2.0.10.

Comment: thanks! my project made by jdk 8. so i need use `org.andromda.thirdparty.jaxb2_commons:parent-pointer-plugin:1.0` any document's for this plugin?

Comment: You can follow the wiki link I pointed out : we take back the plugin in jaxb-tools with the exact same code. We'll backport it in v2 too aftet v4 next release

Comment: The only difference is that the original plugin has a runtime dep on generated code on the plugin itself so you may need to add it in both plugin and dependency section