# access common jaxb object from two different parent classes

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I have two jaxb-annotated classes generated from jax-ws wsimport.  They are "top-level" classes, each referenced from different jax-ws methods.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Level0MessageType", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "payload"
})
public class Level0MessageType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header", required = true)
    protected MessageHeaderType header;
    @XmlElement(name = "Payload", required = true)
    protected Level0PayloadType payload;
 ... etc ..
}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Level1MessageType", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "payload"
})
public class Level1MessageType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header", required = true)
    protected MessageHeaderType header;
    @XmlElement(name = "Payload", required = true)
    protected Level1PayloadType payload;
... etc.
}
```

They both contain a common "header" element.  I need to access that element from the parent object w/o knowing the parent concrete type.  I could define an interface and then have both Level0MessageType and Level1MessageType implement a method to return the header, but that means that whenever wsimport re-generates my java classes, I would lose the changed code. Any better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Which exact environment are you using for code generation (maven, ant, IDE only) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a JAXB class that implements an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271980/generating-a-jaxb-class-that-implements-an-interface)

Comment: Netbeand and Maven.  I am not using jxc, but wsimport to create the classes.

Comment: Please add your maven config. XJC is part of your wsimport toolchain, even if not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I found think link about passing xjc parameter through wsimport.  Looking at the duplicate question.