# How to inherit superclass during jaxb generation for specific element?

Tags: java, xml, maven, inheritance, jaxb

I'm having the following `xsd` schema and want the generated file to extend from a superclass:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="myRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            ...
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

my-binding.xml:

```
<jaxb:bindings    
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"   
    jaxb:version="2.1">

        <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/myRequest.xsd">
            <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='myRequest']">  
                <xjc:superClass name="com.commons.MyMessage"/>
            </jaxb:bindings>
        </jaxb:bindings>    

</jaxb:bindings>
```

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
              <extensions>
                <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-ts:${maven.cxf-xjc-ts.plugin}</extension>
                <extension>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:0.11.0</extension>
              </extensions>
            </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                <!-- Global configuration for all xsd autogenerated resources. default ws location is: src/main/resources/xsd -->
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                    <xsdOptions>
                    <xsdOption>
                    <xsdDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</xsdDir>
                    <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/my-binding.xml</bindingFile>
                    <extensionArgs>
                        <extensionArg>-mark-generated</extensionArg>
                        <extensionArg>-Xts</extensionArg>
                        <extensionArg>-extension</extensionArg>
                        <extensionArg>-Xinheritance</extensionArg>
                    </extensionArgs>
                </xsdOption>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>0.11.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The superclass:

```
public class MyMessage {
    private String sessionID;
    //getter, setter
}
```

Result of `mvn generate-sources`: the class is NOT inherited. But I'm getting no error. Why?

Comment: It needs to be under the global bindings as per [Extending a Common Super Class](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.11/docs/ch05.html#superclass)

Comment: But then **any** element from the xsd would get the superclass. I only want a specific `xs:element[@name='myRequest']`.

Comment: Yes. But, as the docs states, it needs to be in the global bindings. I don't think you can do it per class.

Comment: That's really bad news, but probably you are right and it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JAXB2 Inheritance Plugin ( it allows the implementation of interface or extension of class)

[Generating a JAXB class that implements an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271980/generating-a-jaxb-class-that-implements-an-interface)

https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Inheritance-Plugin