# Jaxb unmarshall enum with abstract superclass to Java - enum-value not generated

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a webservice-standard I have to follow, got a xsd and want to generate the Java classes. Some classes with enums are generated properly, but some are empty and don't have values.

For example this one

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ST_Month">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="01">
        <xsd:annotation>
           <xsd:documentation xml:lang="de">January</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
     </xsd:enumeration>
     <xsd:enumeration value="02">
        <xsd:annotation>
           <xsd:documentation xml:lang="de">February</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
     </xsd:enumeration>
     ...
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

is generated correctly to

```
@XmlType(name = "ST_Month")
@XmlEnum
public enum STMonth {
   /**January */
   @XmlEnumValue("01")
   VALUE_1("01"),

   /** February */
   @XmlEnumValue("02")
   VALUE_2("02"),
    ...
 }
```

But some enums have abstract superclasses like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="STE_Country" abstract="true">
   <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="STE_CountryBasic" final="#all">
   <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="dt:STE_Country">
         <xsd:enumeration value="01">
            <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation>USA</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
         </xsd:enumeration>
         <xsd:enumeration value="02">
            <xsd:annotation>
               <xsd:documentation>GERMANY</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
         </xsd:enumeration>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The result of the generation is this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "STE_CountryBasic")
public class STECountryBasic extends STECountry
{
}
```

I also added my own complexType for 'MyOwnCountry' with country values that are missing in STE_Country but needed in my application. But the generated class is the same empty result as STECountryBasic.

What do I have to do so the enum-values in STECountryBasic are generated?

Additionally, I'm generating via maven with the cxf-codegen-plugin

Comment: Well STE_CountryBasic is a complex type with a superclass, enums can't have superclasses. how would you expect it to be generated?

Comment: It would be cool if a 'public enum STECountryBasic' would be generated, optionally with a comment 'relates to STECountry'.
Is that possible without changing the xsd? Maybe with config in jaxb-bindings?

Comment: You will need STE_Country to generate an interface rather than a class that STE_Country then implements rather than extends. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271980/generating-a-jaxb-class-that-implements-an-interface which asked for the same thing IIUC.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it

Comment: Unfortunatly I didn't get the solution with the interface working.
But I found a way to transform the xsd via XSL, so the STE_CountryBasic looks like the ST_Month in the xsd. A second generation-step creates another class STE_ContryBasicValues as an enum.
@daniu Thanks anyway for your proposal.